# Screen will not render unless resized in libgdx using tiled map

Tags: java, android, libgdx, tiled

It was all working great and then I tried to run it on an android and this started happening. I worked on it for a while then thought, ok let's go back to the bare bones and see if I can fix it there, no such luck. I have Main screen and a intro screen that render and work properly, I am loading assets all this time. When I go to the game screen it is cleared and when I resize it the map shows up. Please take a look and tell me what is wrong.

```
public class GameScreen extends ScreenAdapter {    
    private Viewport viewport;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    private SpriteBatch batch;

    private TiledMap tiledMap;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer orthogonalTiledMapRenderer;

    private HowlersPlatform game;

    public GameScreen(HowlersPlatform game){
        this.game = game;
    }
    @Override
    public void show(){
        super.show();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(Constants.WORLD_WIDTH, Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT, camera);
        viewport.apply(true);

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        tiledMap = Assets.map; // AssetsClass.instance.maps.themap;
        orthogonalTiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap,batch);
        orthogonalTiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta){
        super.render(delta);
        update(delta);
        clearScreen();
        draw();    
    }

    private void clearScreen() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(Color.TEAL.r, Color.TEAL.g, Color.TEAL.b, Color.TEAL.a);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void draw(){    
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.projection);
        batch.setTransformMatrix(camera.view);

        orthogonalTiledMapRenderer.render();    
    }

    public void update(float delta){    
    }    
}
```

Comment: What are you doing in the `resize()` method? You are setting a viewport in `show()` but I'm not seeing you using it. My bet is that in `resize()` you set up the camera properly and if you do the same in `show()` that would fix your issue.

Comment: Worked, the map is offset a tile up, but I can work with that. I didn't know that resize was so important.

Comment: With a proper `resize()` it just makes sure everything is scaled correctly and remains clickable when you resize the game window. So I figured if it was not working initially but only after resize you are doing something wrong with settings things up.

Comment: I have the same problem some time ago ,Override resize method and update viewport solve your problem  @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) 
        viewport.update(width, height);
    }

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, that was the problem.